# Symbol.prototype Comparison Error

Tags: javascript

Why do I get this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Symbol.prototype [ @@toPrimitive ] requires that 'this' be a Symbol
```

when I run this code?

```
3 == Symbol.prototype
```

I'm still trying to work out the reason why by myself and so far using a `try-catch` block to hold it down for awhile but I want a reason for the error.

Comment: Why are you running this code in the first place?

Comment: It's for a personal project of mine.
I wanted to create a backup of object prototypes and all their properties in case of situations like this: `String.prototype.toLowerCase = null; "Hello, World!".toLowerCase() /* error */`.

So a backup of prototypes and their properties would remove this problem `String.prototype.toLowerCase = null; BackedUpStringPrototype.toLowerCase.call("Hello, World!") // 'hello, world!'`

Comment: …assuming that `Function.prototype.call` was not messed with, I see. But it still doesn't explain why you'd compare the `Symbol.prototype` to a number using `==`.

Comment: It was part of my tests while debugging the project and I noticed this error, which was quite new to me at the time.

Comment: OK, so not an actual problem in the code but something that got you curious when you came across it? Using `===` should solve the problem better than `try`/`catch`.

Comment: Yea, definitely. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because performing `==` (sloppy) comparison tries to convert `Symbol.prototype` to primitive value using `@@toPrimitive` but this will work only with symbol type and `Symbol.prototype` is not of a symbol type but has a type of object.

You can do this for example, calling `Symbol()` creates a new value that has a type of symbol and therefore can be converted into its primitive value by using `@@toPrimitive`.

```js
console.log(Symbol() == 3);
```

or use `===` instead of `==` (by using strict equality, JS engine will not try to convert `Symbol.prototype` to its primitive value)

```js
console.log(Symbol.prototype === 3);
```

or even compare it to other object using `==` (that will not try to convert symbol.prototype to its primitive value either)

```js
console.log(Symbol.prototype == {});
```

But the whole testing is rather meaningless because you can't really change `Symbol.prototype` so it will never be equal to `3`, therefore you can simply replace your comparison code with just `false`.

Doing something like this `Symbol.prototype = 3;` will never work since `Symbol.prototype` is read-only property of `Symbol` function, which is part of a browser's native code.

Answer (score 1):

`3 == Symbol.prototype` performs the following operations (likely known parts kept short):

- Attempt to coerce `Symbol.prototype` to a primitive by calling `ToPrimitive` with it as argument, which in turn will use [`Symbol.prototype[@@toPrimitive]`](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-symbol.prototype-@@toprimitive) (with `this` being set to `Symbol.prototype`). This is due to [loose equality](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-abstract-equality-comparison) doing coercion and the first operand being a number.
- `Symbol.prototype[@@toPrimitive]` in turn calls [`thisSymbolValue(this value)`](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-properties-of-the-symbol-prototype-object). Here you can start noticing the problem, `this` is not a Symbol.
- `thisSymbolValue` is specified to throw a TypeError (no further details, you will also get different messages on chrome and FF<sup>[1]</sup> for example) when `this` is neither a Symbol nor an object with [[SymbolData]].

---

[1]: "TypeError: [Symbol.toPrimitive] method called on incompatible Object" on my FF 60.0.1

Answer (score 1):

When you try to compare a primitive (`3`) and object (`Symbol.prototype`) it calls `@@toPrimitive` method on object, as can be seen here:

```js
let obj = {
  [Symbol.toPrimitive](){
    console.log("@@toPrimitive is called!");
  }
}

console.log( 0 == obj )
```

`Symbol.prototype[Symbol.toPrimitive]` throws an error when called on `Symbol.prototype` because it wants a symbol as its argument. However, this looks really strange, because symbols are primitives already and don't need such conversion, moreover it simply returns its argument if it's symbol:

```js
let symbol = Symbol();
console.log(symbol === symbol[Symbol.toPrimitive]());
```